# Why using endLineWithLineFeed in Data.base64EncodedString doesn't add a new line in end of encoded string?

Tags: swift, base64

I would like the swift code to have same behavior as the following Java Android code

### Java Android

```
byte[] binary = {1, 2, 3};
// adheres to RFC 2045
String output = Base64.encodeToString(binary, Base64.DEFAULT);
// "AQID\n"
android.util.Log.i("CHEOK", output);
// "5"
android.util.Log.i("CHEOK", "" + output.length());
```

### Swift

```
import Foundation

let binary: [UInt8] = [1, 2, 3]
let output = Data(binary).base64EncodedString(options: [.endLineWithLineFeed, .lineLength76Characters])
// "AQID"
print(output)
// "4"
print(output.count)
```

Even though I'm using `[.endLineWithLineFeed, .lineLength76Characters]` as options, the new line isn't added to the end of encoded string.

May I know what am I missed out?

Answer (score 1):

As Rob Napier suggested, `.endLineWithLineFeed` is not the option to *add a new line to the end of encoded string*.

It specifies to use a single LineFeed as an End_of_Line. As you know, many internet standards use CRLF as an End_of_Line, so `base64EncodedString(options:)` uses CRLF without this option.

```
let data = Data(0..<(76*3/4)*2) //Exactly two lines
let base64 = data.base64EncodedString(options: [.lineLength76Characters])
debugPrint(base64)
//                                                                               \/\/
//->"AAECAwQFBgcICQoLDA0ODxAREhMUFRYXGBkaGxwdHh8gISIjJCUmJygpKissLS4vMDEyMzQ1Njc4\r\nOTo7PD0+P0BBQkNERUZHSElKS0xNTk9QUVJTVFVWV1hZWltcXV5fYGFiY2RlZmdoaWprbG1ub3Bx"
let base64LF = data.base64EncodedString(options: [.endLineWithLineFeed, .lineLength76Characters])
debugPrint(base64LF)
//                                                                               \/
//->"AAECAwQFBgcICQoLDA0ODxAREhMUFRYXGBkaGxwdHh8gISIjJCUmJygpKissLS4vMDEyMzQ1Njc4\nOTo7PD0+P0BBQkNERUZHSElKS0xNTk9QUVJTVFVWV1hZWltcXV5fYGFiY2RlZmdoaWprbG1ub3Bx"
```

Comment: Thanks. Ever wonder how I can add linefeed to end of encoded String event its length is smaller than 76? Or, the behavior of Android's `Base64.DEFAULT` is non standard? (They claim it adheres to RFC 2045)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't what `.endLineWithLineFeed` does. From the docs:

> When a maximum line length is set, specify that the line ending to insert should include a line feed.

Your data does not exceed the maximum line length, so no line ending is inserted.